# Send generated file with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

How to send a xlsx file from automatically posted form? Code will explain what I mean:

```
public ActionResult SendForm()
{
    ViewBag.text1 = "some generated text";

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    // generating file...
    var file = File(ms, "type")
    // ?? ViewBag.XLS = file;

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        frmSubmit.submit();
    });
</script>

<form name="frmSubmit" action="@url" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="text1" value="@ViewBag.text1" />
</form>
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the request with ajax and handling the response? You can make the request with ajax and handle the response when the action is complete, It has a lot of options that could help you, for reference I let you the documentaion of ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/